# Nodejs socket.io client not connecting to server

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I need to implement a chat with **socket.io**, the server runs on the **app.js** and the chat logic is in the **chat.js** file.
In another test project, also on my pc, I implemented a client example.
I don't understand why but no connection to the server takes place, since the client and server console is empty.

App.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const https = require('http')
const { S3Client } = require('@aws-sdk/client-s3')
const socketIO = require('socket.io')
require('dotenv').config()
const multer = require('multer')
const multerS3 = require('multer-s3')
const app = express()
const server = https.createServer(app)

....

const chatModule = require('./chat/chat')
const io = socketIO(server, {
  path: '/chat',
})

....

const startServer = async () => { 
  await mongoose.connect(MONGO_URL)
  server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}...`)
    chatModule(io)
  })
}
startServer()
```

Chat.js:

```
module.exports = io => {
    console.log('okay')
    io.on('connection', socket => {
        console.log('Un utente si è connesso')
    
        // Gestisci l'evento di join della chat room
        socket.on('join', (room) => {
          // Il client si unisce alla chat room specificata
            socket.join(room)
            console.log(`Utente connesso alla chat room: ${room}`)
        })
    
        // Gestisci l'evento di invio del messaggio
        socket.on('message', (data) => {
            const { room, message, userId } = data
            console.log(`Messaggio ricevuto nella chat room ${room}: ${message}`)
    
          // Inoltra il messaggio solo agli utenti nella chat room specificata
            io.to(room).emit('message', message)
        })
    
        // Gestisci l'evento di disconnessione
        socket.on('disconnect', () => {
            console.log('Un utente si è disconnesso')
        }) 
    })
}
```

Client:

```
const io = require('socket.io-client')

const serverUrl = 'http://localhost:4000/chat' // URL del server Socket.IO con l'endpoint "/chat"
const socket = io(serverUrl)

// Funzione per gestire l'evento di connessione al server
socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('Connesso al server Socket.IO')

    // Unisciti a una chat room specifica
    const rooms = ['r1','r2'] // Sostituisci con il nome della chat room desiderata
    rooms.forEach(room => {
        socket.emit('join', room)
        console.log(`Utente connesso alla chat room: ${room}`)
    })
})

// Funzione per gestire l'evento di disconnessione dal server
socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('Disconnesso dal server Socket.IO') 
})

// Funzione per gestire l'evento di ricezione di un messaggio
socket.on('message', data => {
    const { room, message, userId } = data
    console.log('Messaggio ricevuto:', message)
})

// Funzione per inviare un messaggio alla chat room
const sendMessage = (room, message) => {
    const data = { room, message }
    socket.emit('message', data)
}

// Esempio di utilizzo: invia un messaggio alla chat room
sendMessage('r1', 'Ciao a tutti!')
```

On the server console, the console.log "okay" is correctly displayed, so the app.js I think correctly accesses the chat.js